# FieldEquals does not return results for certain fields

Tags: graphql

We have cases wherein Sitecore GraphQL - FieldEquals() method does not return results for certain fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We identified the issue that occurred due to the Template Field name and Template name are the same.

**Eg:**

Carousel-> Template Name

-> **Slide**

-> Image

-> Text

**Slide** -> Template Name

Once we renamed the template name as below, Our query started returning results.

**SlideItem** -> Template Name

**Note:** Field name and Template name should not be the same.